# Python Pandas Don't Repeat Item Labels

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP6Gx.png)

How would I roll up Group, so that the group numbers don't repeat? I don't want to pd.df.groupby, as I don't want to summarize the other columns. I just want to not repeat item labels, sort of like an Excel pivot table.

Thanks!

Comment: Pivot table doesn't do it for you? (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. You will get more help with this if you post your data as formatted text rather than a screenshot, and show us what code you've tried and what your desired output format is. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance on writing a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your dataframe it appears that 'Group' is in the index, the purpose of the index is to label each row.  Therefore, is unusual and uncommon to have blank row indexes.

You you could so this:

```
df2.reset_index().set_index('Group', append=True).swaplevel(0,1,axis=0)
```

Or if you really must show blank row indexes you could do this, but you must change the dtype of the index to str.

```
df1 = df.set_index('Group').astype(str)
df1.index = df1.index.where(~df1.index.duplicated(),[' '])
```